Migrating Publication database in Transaction Replication to another server
We need to migrate Publication database (SQL 2017) in Transaction Replication from old server (windows 2016) to new server with upgraded hardware (windows 2019). Please let me know if below approach works.
Setup log shopping to migrate Publisher database from old server to new server
Take log backup on old server, restore on new server with NoRecovery
Before doing cutover, disable Application logins & disable other SQL jobs
Remove Replication
Drop all pull subscriptions
Drop publications
Drop Distributor
Do cutover
Make the DB Readonly on old server. Restore it with Recovery on new server.
Bring DB online on new server
Setup Replication from new server to subscriber server with 'Replication Support Only' since schema and data is already there on new server
Allow applications to connect to new server
